# Unable to open port 22 for SFTP file transfer (Remote Desktop environment)

Tags: remote-desktop, port, sftp, filezilla, windows-firewall

I have been given access to Remote Desktop environment where I am supposed to set up file transfer between SFTP server and Remote Desktop storage location. Everything is set up correctly (I am using FileZilla) but I am getting connection refused that points to closed port 22. Its important to note that there is some default Global Policy applied by the company that probably overwrites my attempts to open the port.

I have tried:

1. Checking ports on various places -> showing port 22 closed
2. Manually adding FileZilla connection to firewall exceptions
3. Manually adding port 22 to firewall exceptions
4. Turning off firewall temporarily -> ports kept closed nevertheless
5. Googled for quite some time, trying multiple suggested solutions -> no good

I have admin rights to the remote desktop but it seems that Global Policy overwrites my attempts. Is there please a way to open the port or maybe modify Global Policy from my end with admin rights? I would like to go with less intrusive solution, making changes to their default Policy seems to much.

Is there any other way?

There are no issues on side of the SFTP server itself, connection is successful on my second personal laptop that has port 22 open.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sounds like something that your IT team would be better able to help you with.

Comment: You shouldn't need a specific port open to make a connection to a remote device, only allow a remote device, to make that connection.  Now all networks are configured differently so it is possible to also disable outgoing connections on specific ports used by common protocols like SSH.  If you need that connection to do your job, ask for that connection to be allowed, by contacting the IT Administrator for your company. There really isn't any other solution that results in you keeping your job (you could attempt to bypass the restrictions but that could result in your dismissal.

Comment: Thank you @Ramhound thats a clear answer to my question, I will contact my IT guy. Have a good day.